# Same nextval sequence with PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

#### Setup

- CakePHP 2.3.5
- PostgreSQL 8.3
- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3.8
- Windows 7 Ultimate x64

---

#### Problem

When I execute this query 2 twices, return the same value?

```
$sql = "select nextval('auth_num_seq') as nextval";
$nextval = $this->query($sql);

return $nextval[0][0]['nextval'];
```

Why?

I try that too, but doesn't work?

```
$sql = "select setval('auth_num_seq', nextval('auth_num_seq') + 1, false)";
$setval = $this->query($sql);

$sql = "select nextval('auth_num_seq') as nextval";
$nextval = $this->query($sql);

return $nextval[0][0]['nextval'];
```

Comment: There's got to be something else going on here. Please examine your PostgreSQL logs after setting `log_statement = 'all'` and get the sequence of statements your app actually ran on the database server. You're on an outdated and unsupported version of PostgreSQL that you really should upgrade, but that will not be the cause of this problem.

Comment: I know but my customer doesn't want upgrade your postgreSQL, so I can't do nothing. Anyway I don't have access to edit this file... I have just a basic access (select, insert, delete....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in this link: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/how-to-disable-query-caching-td1297496.html

Thanks for **[AD7six](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761202/ad7six)**!!

I need just do that: `$this->query('some sql', false);`. Set the second parameter as **false**.